# C++ Memory Fault in template function <queue>

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, stl, queue

I'm getting a memory fault message at runtime, i'm new to STL so i'm not sure if 
I'm required to handle queue's in a special way like deleting them in functions or whatnot.

I traced the error to this function

```
template <typename T>  
bool contains(std::queue<T> set, T val){
        std::queue<T> hold;
        bool isContained = false;

        if (set.front() == val) isContained = true;
        while(!set.empty()){
                hold.push(set.front());
                set.pop();
                if (set.front() == val) isContained = true;
        }

        while(!hold.empty()){
                set.push(hold.front()); 
                hold.pop();
        }

        return isContained;
}
```

In my main() I successfully call this function 20 times for queue and then on the first time the function is called on a queue the program spits out a "Memory Fault" message between the two loops in the function.

I'm using gnu compiler.

Comment: If you find yourself doing this often it could be a sign that you don't have the right data structure for the job. There are others that wouldn't need the overhead of all that "holding".

Answer (score 2):

In your second call to `set.front()` there is no guarantee that the set isn't empty.

Comment: Thanks! changing the order of the loop did it!